# Show data from database on display per JSON in Xcode

Tags: json, swift, database, xcode, label

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var fname: UILabel!

```
struct Class: Codable {

    let FName: String
    let LName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case FName = "first_name"
        case LName = "last_name"
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://domain(^_^).com/users.php")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let classes = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)

        for myClass in classes {
            print(myClass.FName)
            print(myClass.LName)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fname.text = "I don't know what to wirte here to change the label to the data which I get fron database"
        }
    }
        ).resume()
}
```

}

At the end I just don't know how to rewrite my label text to the data which I get from database. I tried to show the data on a TableView but I couldn't make it, my only way to get help is here, youtube couldn't help me s well.

Comment: You have an array of `Classe` objects. What do you want to show for your label? From where?

Comment: You should read JSON data with `JSONDecoder` only if you are certain that you can fit data into your codable model.  In other words, it will be easier to read data with `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: @Larme  I'm trying to get the data from database and I did it. I get first_name and last_name from database and want to show it on display.

Comment: It's just that according to your code, you should have 3, 4, n `Class` objects, because `classes` is an array. So if you want to put the first one, `if let fName = classes.first.FName { self.fname.text = fName}`, if you want the second, replace `classes.first.FName` with `classes[1].FName`, etc.

Comment: you're awesome bro, it works now. Many thanks :). @Larme

Answer (score -1):

Try this!!

```
for myClass in classes {

        print(myClass.FName)
        print(myClass.LName)

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.fname.text = myClass.FName
        self.lname.text = myClass.LName // In case you have second label
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried this but it didn't work.